# Admob banner doesn't show up with target sdk 30

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, banner

I can't lower the target sdk to 29 because it's the new requirement from google play(Target API level 30 (Android 11) or above)
Has anyone had the same issue?

No issue with target 29 and play-service 12

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
```

Comment: What is the reason for using play-services-ads version 12? That version was released 3 years ago, currently there's version ~20 available. I'm pretty sure you'll need to update to one of the later versions

Comment: @CoffeeCode ,It worked on my phone.I'll try the recent version later.

Comment: @CoffeeCode,Your solution is working.I changed to version 19.Please post your answer so i can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play-services-ads version 12 is a bit old(released 3 years ago), it's possible that API-29 to 30 update deprecated & removed some stuff that makes version 12 work, you will probably need to update to a later version of ads(19-20 are the most recent ones as of this moment).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you if, you convert version low then some methods you 'll get deprecated.
So, When you upload an APK, it needs to meet Google Play’s target API level requirements. New apps and app updates must target Android 10 (API level 29) or higher; except for Wear OS apps, which must target API level 28 or higher.

As you update the target API level for your apps, consider adopting recent platform features to modernize your apps and delight your users.

Consider using CameraX, which is in Beta, to make the most of using the camera.

Use Jetpack components to help you follow best practices, free you from writing boilerplate code, and simplify complex tasks so that you can focus on the code you care about.

Use Kotlin to write better apps faster, and with less code.

Ensure you are following privacy requirements and best practices.

Add dark theme support to your apps.

Add gesture navigation support to your apps.

Migrate your app from Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) to the latest version of Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Take advantage of advanced window management.